# Flutter scrolling action resulting in click instead

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I am not sure if this is emulator problem.

I have a flutter app that has a scrollable card view and upon clicking going into recipe detail page.

When I tried to scroll the card view page, it's automatically clicking into the card instead. I recorded that as gif even though it's without my mouse (i was actually scrolling for the action, you can see that it's clicking and transitioning into the recipe detail page instead)

My recording as GIF here: https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExeHM3eTloa3AzczIzZXBhbTZ4cm1wc3NxaG02Z2IyMDYwb2JjcnFtcSZlcD12MV9pbnRlcm5hbF9naWZfYnlfaWQmY3Q9Zw/ofyWkhCousvIgA0VWN/giphy.gif

As I am using emulator, i am not sure if this is emulator problem, however my other scrollable page that doesn't have clickable card will not have click action. So i wonder if that's my `InkWell onTap` implementation issue.

My card list file, calling my recipe card each to render:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'recipes_card.dart';

class ListRecipesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List resultData;
  final int resultLength;

  const ListRecipesPage({
    super.key,
    required this.resultData,
    required this.resultLength,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Let's Get Cookin' ")),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: resultLength,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return RecipeCard(
                  recipeName: resultData[index]['recipe_name'],
                  estTimeMin: resultData[index]['est_time_min'],
                  availableIngredients: resultData[index]
                      ['available_ingredients'],
                  missingIngredients: resultData[index]['missing_ingredients'],
                  instructions: resultData[index]['instructions'],
                  thumbnailUrl: resultData[index]['imgUrl'],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Recipe card file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'recipe_details_page.dart';

class RecipeCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String recipeName;
  final String estTimeMin;
  final List availableIngredients;
  final List missingIngredients;
  final Map<String, dynamic> instructions;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  const RecipeCard({
    super.key,
    required this.recipeName,
    required this.estTimeMin,
    required this.availableIngredients,
    required this.missingIngredients,
    required this.instructions,
    required this.thumbnailUrl,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => RecipeDetailPage(
                recipeName: recipeName,
                estTimeMin: estTimeMin,
                availableIngredients: availableIngredients,
                missingIngredients: missingIngredients,
                instructions: instructions,
                thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl,
              ),
            ));
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22, vertical: 10),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 180,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
              offset: const Offset(
                0.0,
                10.0,
              ),
              blurRadius: 10.0,
              spreadRadius: -6.0,
            ),
          ],
          image: DecorationImage(
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.white.withOpacity(0.35),
              BlendMode.multiply,
            ),
            image: NetworkImage(thumbnailUrl),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 10.0,
                  vertical: 5.0,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  recipeName,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.schedule,
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          size: 18,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 7),
                        Text("$estTimeMin mins"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove column as parent and set shrinkWrap as false.

Comment: also remove singlechildscrollview

Comment: i tried the above all and still the same

Comment: Try to long press and drag the while pressing is ongoing. Let me know the result. From your code, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: thanks @Rahul yes you are right long press works.